# añadir texto a un Div con Js desde php

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, jquery, ajax

Los datos que estan en el Objeto, realmente los obtengo de una consulta por medio de Ajax a MySQL por PHP.

Lo que necesito es que al momento de dar click en el titulo se desplieguen los datos restantes en el div "solicitudes", los cuales estarian condicionados a que si selecciono el ID 8 en "Solicitudes" despliegue los datos solo de ese titulo. y si es la 9 pues los datos exclusivos de la 9 y asi sucesivamente.

E intentado reutilizar el objeto que obtengo de la consulta en ajax pero al momento de dar el click en el parrafo no se como condicionar a que solo me traiga los datos del P seleccionado, normalmente me muestra siempre el primer parrafo sin importar cual presione.

Si de algo les sirve anexo el pedazo de codigo Ajax.

```
'use stric'
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#actualizar").on('click',function(){
       var data="";
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'php/fuckingpendientes.php',
            data:{"data":data},
            success:function(data){
            var myObj=JSON.parse(data);
              var title=document.querySelector("#request");
```

Espero me puedan ayudar.

```js
    'use stric'
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#actualizar").on('click',function(){
           
           var data={"obj":[
           {nombre_usuario:"Pedro",
           titulo_solicitud: "No enciende el PC", 
           id_solicitud: "8",
           D_solicitud:"Por alguna extraña razón no enciende la PC"},
           
           {nombre_usuario:"Juan",
           titulo_solicitud: "Internet lento", 
           id_solicitud: "9",
           D_solicitud:"¿Mi pc creo que va lenta o es el internet el que va lento?"},
           
           {nombre_usuario:"Victor",
           titulo_solicitud: "No enciende el PC", 
           id_solicitud: "10",
           D_solicitud:"Por alguna razon no enciende la PC"},
           
           {nombre_usuario:"Houdini",
           titulo_solicitud: "No recuerdo mi contraseña", 
           id_solicitud: "11",
           D_solicitud:"¿Tendras los datos de mi correo?"}
           
           
           ]};
         
                     for(var i in data.obj){
                        var p=document.createElement("p");
                        var title=document.querySelector("#request");
                        p.setAttribute("id", data.obj[i].id_solicitud);
                     p.append(data.obj[i].id_solicitud +"  "+ data.obj[i].titulo_solicitud);
                     title.append(p);
                    }//for
    
               document.addEventListener("click",(e) => {
                  if(e.target.tagName.toLowerCase()==="p"){
                   let enlace=document.querySelectorAll("p");
alert("Hasta aquí se que funciona presionar los p ");
//Aquí necesito que dependiendo del Id que se seleccione traiga los datos faltantes para imprimirlos en el div "Solicitud"
                   }
                   });

        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset>
<legend>solicitudes pendientes</legend>

<input type="button" id="actualizar" value="Actualizar">
<br><br>
<div class="pendientes" id="request"> <!-- Aquí las solicitudes -->  
 <tr>ID</tr>
 <tr>Titulo</tr>

 </div>

</fieldset>
<hr>

<!--  Solicitud      -->
<main class="solicitud">
<fieldset>
 <legend>Solicitud</legend>
<br>
<span>Aquí va el nombre del usuario</span>
<br><br>
<label>Urgencia</label>
 
<br><br>

<label>Detalles de solicitud</label><br>

</fieldset>
</main>

<br><br>
```

Answer (score 1):

Te sugiero que no mezcles javascript con jQuery.  Puedes lograr lo que quieres capturando el evento `click` en los `p` asi:

```js
'use stric'
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#actualizar").on('click',function(){
           
           var data={"obj":[
           {nombre_usuario:"Pedro",
           titulo_solicitud: "No enciende el PC", 
           id_solicitud: "8",
           D_solicitud:"Por alguna extraña razón no enciende la PC"},
           
           {nombre_usuario:"Juan",
           titulo_solicitud: "Internet lento", 
           id_solicitud: "9",
           D_solicitud:"¿Mi pc creo que va lenta o es el internet el que va lento?"},
           
           {nombre_usuario:"Victor",
           titulo_solicitud: "No enciende el PC", 
           id_solicitud: "10",
           D_solicitud:"Por alguna razon no enciende la PC"},
           
           {nombre_usuario:"Houdini",
           titulo_solicitud: "No recuerdo mi contraseña", 
           id_solicitud: "11",
           D_solicitud:"¿Tendras los datos de mi correo?"}
           
           
           ]};
         
                     for(var i in data.obj){
                        var p=document.createElement("p");
                        var title=document.querySelector("#request");
                        p.setAttribute("id", data.obj[i].id_solicitud);
                     p.append(data.obj[i].id_solicitud +"  "+ data.obj[i].titulo_solicitud);
                     title.append(p);
                    }//for
          $("p").click(function() {
            var index = $("p").index(this);
            $("#detalles").html($(this).text() + " " + data.obj[index].nombre_usuario);
            
          });
               
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset>
<legend>solicitudes pendientes</legend>

<input type="button" id="actualizar" value="Actualizar">
<br><br>
<div class="pendientes" id="request"> <!-- Aquí las solicitudes -->  
 <tr>ID</tr>
 <tr>Titulo</tr>

 </div>

</fieldset>
<hr>

<!--  Solicitud      -->
<main class="solicitud">
<fieldset>
 <legend>Solicitud</legend>
<br>
<span>Aquí va el nombre del usuario</span>
<br><br>
<label>Urgencia</label>
 
<br><br>

<label>Detalles de solicitud</label><br>
<div id="detalles"></div>
</fieldset>
</main>

<br><br>
```

Comment: Y hay manera de acceder a los otros datos como el nombre de usuario o los detalles de la solicitud. 

Con el ejemplo que me diste me ayudo a entender mejor como funciona pero sigo sin poder acceder a los otros elementos.

Comment: Ya edite mi respuesta, puedes aprovechar el indice de los `p`, que coinciden con el indice de los objetos en tu array.